# How to set the Google Map Attribute to 'greedy' programatically without having to reload/reconstruct the map in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have the following code in javascript which is my default, I have a button for the user to move the map more easily (without having to use both fingers/or CTRL)
I know there's an attribute called `gestureHandling: "greedy"` but I can't figure out how to set it programatically with javascript without presetting the attribute or rebuild/reconstruct the map, how do I do that ?

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 15,
          center: myLatLng,
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          mapTypeControl: false
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store your settings in an object and apply them when you need to using the [setOptions()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.setOptions) function on the map object;

```js
// The Settings Object
let mapSettings = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: myLatLng,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeControl: false
}

// Your initial Map load
window.onload(function(){
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapSettings);
});

// Used when you want to apply different gesture handling
function greedyMap(){
    mapSettings.gestureHandling = 'greedy';
    map.setOptions(mapSettings);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="greedyMap()">Example</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Per the documentation, [`gestureHandling`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions.gestureHandling) is a [MapOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions) property.

`MapOptions` that don't have a dedicated setter/getter can be set using [`setOptions`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.setOptions)

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('btn'), 'click', function() {
  map.setOptions({
    gestureHandling: 'greedy'
  });
});
```

**code snippet:**

```js
/**
 * This sample sets the gesture handling mode to 'cooperative',
 * which means that on a mobile device, the user must swipe with one
 * finger to scroll the page and two fingers to pan the map.
 */
function initMap() {
  var myLatLng = {
    lat: -25.363,
    lng: 131.044
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng,
    gestureHandling: 'cooperative'
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('btn'), 'click', function() {
    console.log("before:" + map.gestureHandling);
    map.setOptions({
      gestureHandling: 'greedy'
    });
    console.log("after:" + map.gestureHandling);

  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="click" id="btn" />
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap"></script>
```